# Reverse known XOR encryption algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, xor

I have XOR encryption and decryption algorithm, and its working, like this code

```
    int Encryption(int A)
    {
        E = (A ^ KEY) + (KEY ^ KEY2);
        return E;
    }
    int Decryption(int E)
    {
        A = (E - (KEY ^ KEY2)) ^ KEY;
        return A; 
    }
```

my problem is, how to get KEY and KEY2 if I know encryption value and decryption value
Example:
for Encryption value 0x53 it should have decryption value 0x47
for Encryption value 0x5E it should have decryption value 0x4C
for Encryption value 0x61 it should have decryption value 0x49

Note
I try to recover my KEY and KEY2 for my lost note

Thanks

Comment: Just to help your searches in the future, the thing you are trying to do is called a "known plaintext attack"

Comment: You haven't given enough data to reconstruct key and key2. `(0x07, 0x14), (0x17, 0x14), (0x47, 0x14), (0x57, 0x14), (0x67, 0x54), (0x77, 0x54)` are possible answers right now.

Comment: I can give more data to reconstruct key and key2, coz I have decrypted and encrypted file, I just compare them to get value pair, but right now I just want someone help me to get key and key2 algorithm or pseudocode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** I will assume the encryption and decryption arithmetic are all done modulo 256.

Since you're encrypting and decrypting individual bytes with two 8-bit keys, the key space of this cipher is 256 times larger than the message space. That means there are 256 possible combinations of `K` and `K2` for each `(A,E)` pair.

Specifically, if `A = (E - (KEY ^ KEY2)) ^ KEY`, then `KEY2 = (E - (A ^ KEY)) ^ KEY`. Using this formula for a given `(A,E)` pair, you can easily iterate through all 256 values of `KEY` and obtain the corresponding value of `KEY2`. Repeat this process for each pair of plaintext/ciphertext characters, and calculate the intersection of all the resulting sets of `(KEY,KEY2)` pairs. With a sufficient number of characters in the plaintext and ciphertext, that should give you a unique result.

I know you tagged this question as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but it's easier to do this sort of thing in Python. The following code probably isn't very efficient, but it doesn't matter because we're only dealing with a toy cipher here.

```python
def retrieve_keys(plain,cipher):
    # Initialize set with all 65536 possible key pairs
    key_pairs = set([(x,y) for x in range(256) for y in range(256)])
    # Intersect this set with the set of 256 possible key pairs for
    # each plaintext/ciphertext pair
    for i in range(len(plain)):
        a, e = ord(plain[i]), ord(cipher[i])
        s = set([])
        # if a = (e - (key ^ key2)) ^ key, then key2 = (e - (a ^ key)) ^ key
        for key in range(256):
            s.add((key, ((e - (a ^ key)) % 256) ^ key))
        key_pairs = key_pairs.intersection(s)
    # Print out the remaining set of possible key pairs
    for kp in key_pairs:
        print "KEY=%d, KEY2=%d" % kp

# Example (should output "KEY=117, KEY2=80" and "KEY=245, KEY2=80"):
plaintext  = "Hello world, this is a test"
ciphertext = "b5>>?z'?,>6~z&BA+zA+z9z&5+&"
retrieve_keys(plaintext,ciphertext)
```

---

**EDIT:** The following C# code was suggested by Eric Lippert:

```
foreach (var kp in 
  Enumerable.Range(0, plain.Length).Aggregate(
    ( from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 256) 
      from y in Enumerable.Range(0, 256) 
      select new { x, y }).ToList(), 
    (pairs, i) => pairs.Intersect(
      from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 256) 
      select new { x, y = 
        ((cipher[i] - (plain[i] ^ x)) % 256) ^ x }).ToList()))
  Console.WriteLine(kp);
```

Comment: Your idea that this is somehow tremendously simpler in Python than C# is... odd.  Here, let me fit your solution into this comment with a hundred characters to spare: `foreach (var kp in Enumerable.Range(0, plain.Length).Aggregate((from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 256) from y in Enumerable.Range(0, 256) select new { x, y }).ToList(), (pairs, i) => pairs.Intersect(from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 256) select new { x, y = ((cipher[i] - (plain[i] ^ x)) % 256) ^ x }).ToList())) Console.WriteLine(kp);`

Comment: I suspect that it is easier in Python because you know Python. I am reminded of the French philosopher who determined that French is the best language because it is the only language where the words are in *the same order that you think them*.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage can you give me link for boolean operation like your final equation KEY2 = (E - (A ^ KEY)) ^ KEY, I still confuse how step by step to get that formula

Comment: @navirius: Work it out with algebra. You are given the equation  `E = (A ^ KEY) + (KEY ^ KEY2)` and asked to solve for `KEY2`.  Start by subtracting from both sides: `E - (A^K) = K^K2`  Now how can you eliminate K from the right hand side?  **Hint: What identities do you know that involve the xor operation?**